# Stata code interpretation

Tags: statistics, stata

I am having difficulties reading a report which uses Stata code. I only know very simple basics of Stata, but even help of Google didn't accelerate my work.
What does the second part of this code do? There is a standard dataset with columns as labels, and rows as observations for each quarter of different years.
I see that time variable is generated and time series is specified. The supporting text says this calculates growth rate (from quarter to quarter), and then normalizes data in some variables. So,

What does

```
`x'_gr = ..
```

part do? I cannot divide it into blocks I would understand.

What does `n(10000)` part do?

```
generate JQ = yq(year, q)
format JQ %tq
sort JQ
tsset JQ
local  varlist "m ma c t"
foreach x of local varlist{
gen `x'_gr=100*(`x'/l.`x' - 1)
}
set obs 10000
kdensity m, gen(MK epanechnikov) n(10000)
kdensity ma, gen(MAK epanechnikov_1) n(10000) 
kdensity c, gen(COK epanechnikov_2) n(10000) 
kdensity t, gen(TK epanechnikov_3) n(10000)
```

Comment: This seems off-topic to me. Nevertheless, some help below in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part loops over variable names and `generate`s new variables from old ones. A `local` macro is used to hold the variable names. If you do not know what macros are, then run `help macro` and follow the link to the manual entry. The Stata **User's Guide** also has relevant information.

A simplified version:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example dataset -----

sysuse auto
keep weight rep78

list in 1/5

*----- example -----

// goal: create new variables from old ones

// set a local macro
local varlist "weight rep78"

// loop over elements of the -local-
foreach x of local varlist {
    // generate new variables appending _gr to original names
    gen `x'_gr = 100 * `x'  
}

list in 1/5, abbreviate(15)
```

Your original code involves time-series data, as implied by `tsset`, and later uses `l.`, which is the lag operator. See `help tsset` and `help tsvarlist`.

If you run `help kdensity` you'll find that the option `n(#)` will:

> estimate density using # points; default is min(N, 50)

This is all basic Stata, but you are looking for help in the wrong places. Stata has excellent built-in documentation: accessible through the `help` command and the extensive .pdf manuals. Start with the [User's Guide](http://www.stata.com/bookstore/users-guide/) which has detailed information on how to search for help.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually R user, and facing Stata because my "colleague" have prepared a report using Stata